# How to keep line with text when create file txt - PHP

Tags: php, html, file, text, url-rewriting

I have code

```
$file = fopen("file.txt",'w+');
if(isset($_POST['email']))
$string = $_POST['email'];;
fwrite($file, $string);
```

$string have value:

```
I HAVE
NEW LINE
```

But after i run my code, i had open file.txt. This see:

```
I HAVE NEW LINE
```

I want keep line same when i input with form.
My form

```
echo '<form method="POST" id="formmail" role="form">' .
    "\n" . '<div class="form-group">' .
        "\n" . '<input type="email" id="from" class="form-control" name="from" placeholder="From Email">' .
    "\n" . '</div>' .
    "\n" . '<div class="form-group">' .
        "\n" . '<input type="email" id="to" class="form-control" name="to" placeholder="To Email">' .
    "\n" . '</div>' .
    "\n" . '<div class="form-group">' .
        "\n" . '<input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Title Email">' .
    "\n" . '</div>' .
    "\n" . '<div class="form-group">' .
        "\n" . '<textarea cols="80" rows="10" id="list" placeholder="Enter List Email" class="form-control"/></textarea>' .
    "\n" . '</div>' .
    "\n" . '<div class="form-group">' .
        "\n" . '<textarea cols="80" rows="10" id="content" placeholder="Enter content Email" class="form-control"/></textarea>' .
    "\n" . '</div>' .
    "\n" . '<button id="OK" class="btn btn-danger">Sent Mail</button>' .
"\n" . '</form>';
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#OK").click(function(e) {
            var email = $('#list').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'mail.php',
                data: 'email='+email,
                success: function(answer){
                    $('.kq').html(answer);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPpH0.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9F0q.png

Comment: You can pass a html break <br />.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you actually have a newline in that string?

Comment: @Sagar <br /> not break line in file text

Comment: Show the HTML code that captures the `email` value.

Comment: Better show the javascript code as well

Comment: I had show javascript

Answer (score 0):

A simple test to see what happens when you actually have a newline in a string that you write to a file would be to run a quick test like this

```
$file = fopen("file.txt",'w+');

if(isset($_POST['email']))
    $string = $_POST['email'];;

$string = "I HAVE\nNEW LINE";    // this definitely has a new line
fwrite($file, $string);
```

If this writes to the file with a newline then your `$_POST['email']` does not have one.

If your email is gathered using

```
<input type="text"
```

then there will not be a newline in the string, if it is gathered using

```
<textarea name="email"></textarea>
```

then it might have one. But I would not expect you to gather an email address using a `<textarea`

If you are using `<input type="email"` then please remember

> email: The element represents one email address. **Line breaks are automatically stripped from the input value**. An invalid email address can be set, but the input field will only satisfy its constraints if the email address satisfies the ABNF production 1*( atext / "." ) "@" ldh-str 1*( "." ldh-str ) where atext is defined in RFC 5322 section 3.2.3, and ldh-str is defined in RFC 1034 section 3.5.

**Actually now I see your HTML there is a more obvious problem !!**

You are using the wrong name for the field containing the email address it should be either `$_POST['from']` or `$_POST['to']`

Or if you expect to be getting data from the

```
<textarea cols="80" rows="10" id="list" placeholder="Enter List Email" class="form-control"/></textarea>'
```

Then you have not actually given this a `name="email"` property so nothing will be returned to $_POST, unless you are using javascript to send the data, in which case SHOW THE JAVASCRIPT CODE.

Comment: $string have value in form input